# How can I define the engine XeLaTex through Overleaf API?

Tags: api, overleaf

According to the [official documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/devs), 'By default, Overleaf tries to detect which TeX engine to use, and it usually chooses pdflatex. If you would like to set the engine explicitly for your new project, **you can pass an engine parameter** with one of the following values: latex_dvipdf, pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex.'. My project has to be compiled with xelatex.
So, considering the given official MWE:

```
<form action="https://www.overleaf.com/docs" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="snip_uri"
       value="https://production-overleaf-static.s3.amazonaws.com/examples/helloworld.tex"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Open in Overleaf">
</form>
```

**where/how do I set the engine parameter to xelatex** through the API (and not by the overleaf menu settings)?

I have tried changing the first line of main.tex to `%!TeX program = xelatex`, but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Overleaf support, the solution is just adding `<input type="hidden" name="engine" value="xelatex">` inside the `<form>`. Now the Overleaf editor/preview open directly in XeLaTex when the form is submitted.